# Unable to run Scala test as a suite in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, unit-testing, jenkins, apache-spark

I am running Scala (and Spark) tests using FunSuite in Eclipse (Kepler). I have been able to successfully run the tests. I then created a new package (in the same source folder and project) and am running into a problem.

When I select run as:

[image]

I am able to successfully run my tests using both the 1st (ScalaTest – File) and 3rd (ScalaTest – Test) options. However, when I try and run method 2 (ScalaTest – Suite), I get:

```
***RUN ABORTED ***
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.domain.gotime.rdd.Test1
```

Why is that I am getting this error for the Suite only? I am planning on this being run automatically with Jenkins – and want to know if I need to fix this, and if so how?

I have looked over [this page](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_eclipse) but am still confused as to why it isn't working.

Comment: That's weird that the third option works but the second not, it is hard to tell what's wrong with currently available info, one thing you can check is that com.domain.gotime.rdd.Test1 is in the classpath of the auto-created Run Configuration

Comment: @Chua Chee Seng that was it - I needed to add the classpath (which I did by following the *IF YES* directions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005993/java-eclipse-how-to-configure-run-configurations-classpath-for-junit-test

Please add as an answer and I will accept. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that com.domain.gotime.rdd.Test1 is in the classpath of the auto-created Run Configuration.